# if else statement not removing class based on statement in jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to add or remove a class from an SVG element hence why I am using attr() instead of toggleClass. but it seems as if it is only reading the if statement once instead of every time I click it. It will add the class 'ani' but will not remove it. Please any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Here is my script:

```
$('.svgContainer').on('click', '.menu-icon', function () {
    var line1 = $('.line1');
    var line2 = $('.line2');
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.moduleSlide').toggleClass('open');
    if (line1.hasClass('ani')) {
        line1.attr('class', 'line1 line');
        line2.attr('class', 'line2 line');
        console.log('el does not have class ani');
    } else if (!line1.hasClass('ani')) {
        line1.attr('class', 'line1 line ani');
        line2.attr('class', 'line2 line ani');
        console.log('el has class ani');
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="svgContainer">
    <div class="menu-icon">
        <svg class="lineWrap" width="50" height="50">
            <g class="line1 line">
                <rect width="13" height="2" />
            </g>
            <g class="line2 line">
                <rect width="13" height="2" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If for whatever reason you cannot use `toggleClass` what makes you think you can use `hasClass`?

Comment: Your [code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/7ghvj2n4/), please provide an example that demonstrates the issue. NOTE: There isn't any point in your `else if`... just `if` then `else { }` would do the same

Comment: I never thought of it that way, any suggestions on how to get around it?

Comment: Musefan: I agree with how the if else statement should be structured. I was just trying anything at that point to see if it would work. I obviously failed.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller: Fair enough, but like I said, it does seem to work. In Chrome at least anyway... seems its fixed for JQuery 3.0 (as per AtheistP3ace's answer), I tested this too and it does fail pre 3.0

Comment: try to use    $(line1).addClass("ani");  $(line1).removeClass("ani");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the class attribute works the same with SVGs, you will need to do this in order to get a correct true/false.

```
line1[0].classList.contains('ani')
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/ehd33boy/

It seems that jQuery silently fails on SVGs because className returns a SVGAnimatedString object instead of a normal string.

EDIT: It seems this was fixed in jQuery 3.0 but it stills fails as of 2.1.3

You can also do something like this as well:

```
line1.attr('class').indexOf('ani') !== -1
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/ehd33boy/1/

Comment: You are a genius, never even considered that using javascript straight up would make a difference. thank you!

Comment: No problem!! Happy to help.